# What are the differences between std::decay and pass-by-value?

Tags: c++, c++11

The specification of `std::decay` in [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) leaves the following note:

> [ Note: This
>   behavior is similar to the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1),
>   array-to-pointer (4.2), and
>   function-to-pointer (4.3) conversions
>   applied when an lvalue expression is
>   used as an rvalue, but also strips
>   cv-qualifiers from class types **in order
>   to more closely model by-value
>   argument passing.** — end note ]

It seems to me that ideally `std::decay` would model by-value argument passing **exactly**, but for some reason it's not defined that way.

I think it could be defined in terms of template argument deduction in which case the implementation could also be defined to leverage template argument deduction to **exactly** model by-value argument passing.

```
template <typename T>
struct decay {
  private:

  template <typename U>
  static U impl(U);

  public:

  using type = decltype(impl(std::declval<T>()));
};
```

Questions:

1. What are the differences between `std::decay` and by-value argument passing?
2. Is `std::decay` **designed** to not model by-value argument passing exactly?
3. Would the implementation above model it exactly?

Comment: One key difference is that your implementation will not work if `T` is non-copyable, whereas `decay` will still do something reasonable. Hence *models* but not *is*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::decay` was proposed in [N2069](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2069.html), the motivating example was `std::make_pair` return a pair of `decay`-ed types, which is very nearly how [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) is implemented in C++11 (there is a slight exception for `reference_wrapper`). Note how the proposal originally did not remove *cv*-qualifiers or top-level reference - I assume this is simply an oversight.

As to the reason it simply *models* by-value argument passing instead of *duplicates* it, I can only guess that it may be that the latter is too restrictive. Consider:

```
struct A {
    A(const A& ) = delete;
};

using T1 = std::decay<A>::type; // T1 == A
using T2 = your_decay<A>::type; // compile error
                                // use of deleted function A(const A&)
```

I cannot speak as to whether or not it was explicitly specified in this way to allow for `decay`-ing noncopyable types - but it seems better design to allow this to compile.

Comment: In cases where the above implementation and `std::decay` compile (no early or late errors), can they ever return a different type?  Or is `std::decay` a strict extension?

Comment: @Yakk I believe it's a strict extension.